# differential form is exact on $ U \cup V$

Tags: differential-forms

Let $ U ,V \subset \mathbb R ^n$ two simply connected open sets such that $ \displaystyle{ U \cap V}$ is a connected set.

If $\omega$ is a **closed** 1-form wich is exact in $U$ and $V$ prove that: *$\omega$ is exact in $ \displaystyle{ U \cup V}$*

Comment: I can't see why $f_1 - f_2$ is constant on $U \cap V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the fact that a differential form on a simply connected open set is exact (result from Poincaré). Since $U$ and $V$ are simply connected open set, we can find functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $df_1=\omega$ on $U$ and $df_2=\omega$ on $V$.

On $U\cap V$, we have $d(f_1-f_2)=df_1-df_2=\omega-\omega=0$, and since $U\cap V$ is connected, $f_1-f_2$ is constant on $U\cap V$. Therefore, we can define $F$ by $F(x)=f_1(x)-f_1(x_0)$ for $x\in U$, $F(x)=f_2(x)-f_2(x_0)$, where $x_0\in U\cap V$ (if $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, the result is clear).

Comment: If $ x \in U \cap V$ what is F(x) ?

Comment: Silly question. Thank you very much for your reply!